# Kotlin App Keeps crashing immediately when running

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging, mobile

I am very new to programming in general and I have just started coding in Kotlin in Android Studio. I'm trying to build a simple "Check if number is even or odd" app but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My app crashes immediately when I start it up on the emulator.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var enternumber : EditText
    private lateinit var button: Button
    private lateinit var output: TextView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        enternumber = findViewById(R.id.et_number)
        button = findViewById(R.id.btn_click)
        output = findViewById(R.id.tv_output)
        val enternum: Int = enternumber.text.toString().toInt()

        button.setOnClickListener {
            if (enternum % 2 == 0)
                output.text = ("Number is even")
            else
                output.text = ("Number is odd")
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error (check the logs)?

Comment: So the it executes the tasks fine and the it says the launch succeeded, and yet it still crashed when I start it. That's what's got me most confused

Comment: And logcat gives no indication of what the error is?

Comment: logcat states that there are "no debuggable processes" so it pretty much gives me nothing at all. From what I can tell, the code itself is fine

Comment: Well, the answer below points out a potential problem. For more help I think you'll need to provide a full [mre] (you gave us the activity already; is there any other code? What about the layout file(s)?).

Comment: Sometimes you may have to close and re-open the emulator to get the Logcat to work, or try selecting your app from the drop down there, but if there is a crash there *will* be a stack trace there. Even for normal operation, there should be a ton of output there, which is your indication that the logcat is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn to use the logcat to get helpful exception stacktraces for problem diagnosis. [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

One problem here is obvious. Move the

```
val enternum: Int = enternumber.text.toString().toInt()
```

inside the onclick listener. At `onCreate()` phase there's no content in the edittext and `toInt()` will surely fail. Upon click there might be a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your app keeps crashing due to this:
val enternum: Int = enternumber.text.toString().toInt()

You have to create two number vals.  One to display as a String, and one to use as an Int in your if statement that is combined with the String.

Here is some code that will accomplish what you are trying to do.  I put it into a function just to make it more readable:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var enternumber: EditText
private lateinit var button: Button
private lateinit var output: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button = findViewById(R.id.btn_click)
    output = findViewById(R.id.tv_output)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        getEvenOrOdd()
    }

}

fun getEvenOrOdd() {
    enternumber = findViewById(R.id.et_number)
    val displayNumber = enternumber.text.toString()
    val newNum = displayNumber.toInt()
    val even = "Number is even"
    val odd = "Number is odd"
    if (newNum % 2 == 0) {
        output.text = even
    } else {
        output.text = odd
    }

}
```

}